# tuple unpacking in a list cannot be performed

Tags: python

Basically the question is to see if a number is a t-prime number or not (t-prime number has 3 distinct positive divisors), I have written the code it gives me a list like below:

```
[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 5), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 6)]
```

I need a func to return the number of j in each i value (i,j) in the list above, like 4 comes with three divisors, 5 comes with 2 etc..

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/230/B

'CODE'

```
# 230B

n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))

lst = []
for j in range(len(a)):
    i = 1 
    while i <= a[j]:
        if a[j]%i == 0:
            lst.append((a[j],i))
        i += 1
print(lst)
```

please refer to previous page

Comment: What is the problem? It is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your goal is to count the number of tuples with a given first element. Try this:

```py
counter = {}
values = [(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 5), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 6)]

for value, divisor in values:
    current = counter.get(value, 0) + 1
    counter[value] = current
```

Then, to get the count of a given value, use `counter[n]`. For instance, `counter[4]` would be `3`.

If your divisors are not guaranteed to be unique, then use sets for your dictionary values instead:

```py
counter = {}
values = [(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 5), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 6)]

for value, divisor in values:
    if value not in counter:
        counter[value] = set()
    counter[value].add(divisor)
```

Then, you can get the number of divisors with `len(counter[n])`. So, `len(counter[4])` would be `3`.